# Reconciling two descriptions of fluorescence

Tags: radiation, absorption, photon-emission, fluorescence

I am currently studying the textbook *Infrared and Raman Spectroscopy: Principles and Spectral Interpretation*, second edition, by Peter J. Larkin. **Section 9. Selecting the Raman Excitation Wavelength**, says the following:

> Fluorescence involves excitation of a fluorophore within an absorption band, followed by nonradiative transition and fluorescence emission.

The [Wikipedia article for fluorescence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluorescence#Physical_principles) says the following:

> Fluorescence occurs when an excited molecule, atom, or nanostructure, relaxes to a lower energy state (possibly the ground state) through emission of a photon.

Notice that the Wikipedia article description does not mention fluorophores. So how does one reconcile these two descriptions of fluorescence?

Comment: *fluorophore* is just a generic term for the *molecule, atom, or nanostructure* that absorbs a photon and becomes excited.

Comment: @JohnRennie Oh, ok, that makes sense. Thank you for the clarification.